# How could I absolute images without overlapping to another image?

Tags: html, css

[image: Sample]I am styling my Galleries in 3 rows and inline each other edge to edge with different sizes.

I have code where I can fetch the images to database, and it will post to my website with three rows.

```
.images-item {
min-height: 1px;
float: left;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
position: absolute;
}

<div class="images-item">
<?php echo "<img class='img-size' 'img- 
responsive'id='hp'src='http://localhost/upload_images/".$rs['image']."'/>"; ?>
</div>
```

I like my images inline in 3 rows with normal sizes, edge to edge without overlapping to other images.

Comment: can you please show your html code as well?

Comment: hi @escapeVelocty just added more codes

Comment: lookslike you can easily solve this with flexbox

Comment: hi @Philipp Sander I have no idea to flexbox

Comment: @MarvinAcosta good time to expand your skillset and learn it

Comment: @PhilippSander thank you for pushing me to figure out my code problem ^^ I am posted my answered problem below.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use flexboxes, with a vertical-alignment.

Don't forget to put a max-height for your container :)

Hope it helps !

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  max-height:600px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img{
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/260
" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/310
" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200
" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/250
" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/550
" />
</div>
```

Comment: This exactly output I needed. but all images are comes from database. so there is only one code for echo.

Comment: @MarvinAcosta I putted images here so that you can see the result. In your case, just replace all the img tags with :
`<?php echo "<img class='img-size' 'img- 
responsive'id='hp'src='http://localhost/upload_images/".$rs['image']."'/>"; ?>
  </div>`. If you wanna learn Flexboxes I'll suggest you this interactive website : https://flexboxfroggy.com/. And if my answer fits what you expected then please mark it as resolved :)

Comment: same output. nothing change

Comment: @MarvinAcosta do you see your images with this code ? I don't understand if it's a problem with your PHP or with the CSS. 
Maybe you just need something like that: 
`<?php
foreach ($arr as $image) {
 echo '<img src="'http://localhost/upload_images'/'.$rs['image'].'.png">'; }
?>` With $arr being the array of pictures you get from your database

Comment: I tried your code but it won't work. it display 1 row in line.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute` and float and instead use `display:inline-block`. Then give the items a width, in your case the width of the items would be 33%;

```
.images-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%; /* Number of items divide by 100 */
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    }
```

Update:

You can achieve what you looking for with `flex`.

```
.item-parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}


<div class="item-parent">
  <div class="images-item">
    <?php echo "<img class='img-size' 'img- 
responsive'id='hp'src='http://localhost/upload_images/".$rs['image']."'/>"; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @Rust thank you for your answer. but I already did that code, but the images won't placing to the right position.

Comment: @MarvinAcosta Then I think you should remove float and use `display:inline-block`

Comment: thank you for keeping posting the possible answer. but its same result.

Comment: @MarvinAcosta Updated my answer... Try flexbox

Comment: same display output. maybe all you codes are correct. but please don't forget that all my images are comes from database. so there is only one source to be echo

Comment: @MarvinAcosta Hmm, are images taking 100% width of its container? If not then I think it should... `<img width="100%" ... />`

Comment: I tried your code but it won't work. it display 1 row in line.

Comment: @MarvinAcosta Add a `max-height` to your `.item-parent`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.column {
  -ms-flex: 33%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 33%;
  max-width: 33%;
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code but it won't work. it display 1 row in line.

Comment: @MarvinAcosta It shouldn't. I think you misunderstood the answer. If you give your html version of code (without php) I will give my answer according to that so that you will be able to understand how to make rows and columns for my example's procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the below jsfiddle link for the above question related to aligning the images.

[Align Images in a row](https://jsfiddle.net/kmanmeet12/63hu5am7/13/)

If you want to show it, edge to edge then remove `padding:10px;` from the css.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for posting and giving some ideas. I've already did the right code for my problem. I'll share it here for someone's in need.

```
.boxfourcolumns { 
float: left; padding-left: 10px; 
padding-right: 10px; 
width: 33.3%; 
display: inline-block; 
margin-bottom: 20px; 
position: relative; 
z-index: 0; 
}

<div class="container">

            <?php
                $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM galleries ORDER BY id 
            DESC") or die("Error fetching data...");
                 while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            ?>

            <!-- image 1 -->
            <div class="boxfourcolumns">
                <span class="gallery">
                    <?php echo "<img class='img-size' 'img-responsive' 
                     id='hp'src='http://localhost/upload_images/".$rs['image']."'/>"; 
            ?>
                </span>
            </div>
            <!-- image 1 -->

            <?php } ?>

 </div>
```